# Can I use "open" to mean "create an account"?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

With *I have opened facebook* I mean I created an account.

Is this sentence correct? Could I use it? If not, could you kindly help me with the right sentences I can use to describe that, now, I have a Facebook account?

Yesterday I had an English class which was about speaking. While I was speaking, I told my teacher I have opened Facebook to chat in English with good friends from around the world and I don't know if it was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use "open" to mean "create", when talking about something like a *new* account or a user profile:

> I deleted Facebook about a year ago but then I felt like I was missing out so I **opened** a new account today.

However we also use "open" to mean "start up a program or application".

> Hey, **open** up Facebook and check out the hilarious cat video I just posted.

So you can say you *opened* a Facebook account, and then, afterward, you *open* Facebook periodically to chat with friends (and post cat videos).

Note you can also *open* something like a new bank account, a new document (on the computer), a new project, and many other things:

> To create a new spreadsheet, just **open** Microsoft Excel and click on "**open** new file" in the upper left of the screen.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew but want to address your specific question which is, "With 'I have opened facebook' I mean I created an account. Is this sentence correct?"  Technically, no. The correct way to say that sentence  is, "I have opened a Facebook account." That means you've created an account, not merely opened the Facebook application.

Comment: @Headblender  agreed.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hello @Headblnder! Thank you very much for your clarification! If I said I have opened Facebook, just this! What does it mean?

Comment: @MuradYusuf  If you say "I opened Facebook" it means you started up the application (by touching the icon on your smartphone, etc.).  You would have to be more specific if you mean to say: "I opened a new Facebook account".

Comment: Exactly right @Andrew. Do you understand the difference now, @MuradYusuf?

Comment: Yes, @Headblender I do! Thank you very much! It is clear now!

Comment: @Andrew, thank you very much! Chapeau Mr Andrew and Mr Headblender!